# Twitter bootstrap weird top and left margin

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying out twitter bootstrap and am new to CSS/HTML. Here's my simple HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  ......
</head>
<body>
  <div class="navbar">
    <div class="navbar-inner">
      <div class="container">
          <a class="brand" href="#">Test App</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

It renders and page that has a weird top and left margin:[image]

Comment: please show your css file and tell what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check in firebug, either of your container - `navbar, navbar-inner, container` may have `padding` or `margin`.

Answer (score 2):

If you would like the navbar to be full width and stuck to the top then add the navbar-fixed-top class to the navbar like so:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
```

Answer (score 1):

With regards to the top margin try `body {
      padding-top: 0;
}`